# Microsoft Edge is messing up my CFDocument

Tags: pdf, windows-10, microsoft-edge, coldfusion-11, cfdocument

Has anyone had any problems with Microsoft Edge and CFDocuments? I have one in PDF format that is not behaving properly when opened with Edge. 
Specifics:
Page A has a form and a submit button. When the form is submitted, it carries it to Page B and builds a PDF document which can be saved or printed normally from the browser. But when opened with Edge, it automatically just saves the pdf and does not open the page at all. The function works in every other browser and every other OS, just not Windows 10 with Edge. Has an one run across this problem or know of any possible patches?

Comment: can you check via the F12 Developer Tools the values of the Http Header content-disposition between browsers? Do they differ?

Comment: neither page says anything about content disposition. I see content type, length and encoding. No disposition. But there is on difference on any of those.

Comment: try adding a content disposition value of inline. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547469/content-disposition-being-ignored-in-ie-9-and-firefox-13

Comment: That did not work. Still Having the same issue. I tried to use the suggested  code from the link, but CF11 does not accept the <rule> tag.

Comment: Can you link to a live resource that shows the issue, and/or share the HTTP headers for the response?